# Liferay: Global CSS Styling on Selected Portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I tried liferay-hook.xml:

```
<custom-jsp-dir>/WEB-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
<custom-jsp-global>true</custom-jsp-global>
```

and create file on **/WEB-INF/jsp/html/common/themes/top_js-ext.jspf** and put all my `<link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` there. but it will applied to all pages on my page. I want to know on how to apply global styling on selected portlet on liferay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to introduce global CSS styles is through your theme, not through a JSP override. Create a theme that contains the CSS you'd like to use. This way, Liferay will include your CSS in the minified version, compact all files to be downloaded in just a single request. Plus, your changes are probably relevant for a specific theme anyways.

Use your browser's DOM inspection tools to analyse the CSS selector you need. Each portlet declares specific classes that you can easily address. e.g.

```
.portlet-navigation {
    background-color: red;
}
```